# Open sourced alternative to airbrake?

Tags: exception, error-logging, airbrake

Is there an alternative open sourced version of a system like http://airbrake.io/pages/home

I would use airbrake but its purely for internal software and exception management

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Yes there is. It's https://github.com/errbit/errbit ; It's fully compliant with our notifier / API.

We offer a hosted version of Airbrake if you're a large company.

Regards,
Ben from Airbrake.

Comment: Thanks for this, wrote a blog post on setting it up diarmuidmoloney.wordpress.com/2012/08/29/open-source-application-monitoring-catching-exceptions/

Comment: @Diarmuid I think it should be [http://diarmuidmoloney.wordpress.com/2012/08/29/open-source-application-monitoring-catching-exceptions/](http://diarmuidmoloney.wordpress.com/2012/08/29/open-source-application-monitoring-catching-exceptions/)

Comment: @Ben - posts like yours make me happy to be a developer.  This is in many ways a great industry to be working in.

Comment: @Ben - I agree with Duncan.  To me it says a lot that a developer from the company helps to seek a potential customer find the right solution, even if it's not the product they work on.  +1 for Airbrake!

Comment: Even the add-on libraries for Airbrake reference how to set up for Errbit. Many Kudos Airbrake! https://github.com/airbrake/airbrake-python